# How can I define an array of tuples (datetime,int)

Tags: jsonschema

I need to define a property that is a list of datetime/int pairs.
What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In `jsonschema` a tuple is an array of fixed length. You can define the type of each member in that fixed length array.

In your case:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "maxItems" : 2,
        "minItems" : 2,
        "items" : [{
                "type" : "string",
                "format" : "date-time"
            }, {
                "type" : "int"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

You should take into account that not all validators will implement the  `date-time` format, although it is pretty common.